# Can I turn a sidewaystable into a figure?

Tags: floats, rotating

I'm hoping I can get a quick answer to this question, and I don't have time to make a MWE right now. If I have made a sideways table and used it to layout some images nicely, but I would like the overall table to actually be a figure so that it:

1. is titled "Figure xx",
2. shows up in the LOF,
3. counts towards the figure counter, and
4. no longer counts towards table sum or LOT.

Can this be easily done?

Here's a rough code snippet to show what I mean. I'd like to do something equivalent to taking the following:

```
\begin{sidewaystable}[htpb]
\begin{tabular}
... table contents ... 
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

and turning it into:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\begin{tabular}
... table contents ... 
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{figure}
```

However, just wrapping the table in a figure environment like that gives me errors right away at `\begin{sidewaystable}` saying it's "not in outer par mode." I also think that even if this did compile, it would simultaneously increment table AND figure counters.

Comment: Why do you use a `table` environment inside `sidewaystable`? `sidewaystable` creates a floating object similar to `table` but rotated. Nesting `table` inside `sidewaystable` will produce errors.

Comment: I only recently started using tables, and have been going off a tutorial online which shows `tabular` nested inside a `table`, so I had the impression that in that setup, to rotate it sideways, you replaced `table` with `sidewaystable` but kept the nested `tabular`. The approach I've shown works fine for me with no errors.

Comment: of course, you can nest `tabular` inside `sidewaystable`, all right, but please notice that in the code you posted you are nesting `table` inside `sidewaystable`, and this will produce errors.  
Perhaps it was just a typo in your code snippet, but you could fix it.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've updated my example code. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `sidewaysfigure` environment instead of `sidewaystable`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\centering
\rule{3cm}{3cm}
\caption{test rotated figure}
\label{fig:test}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks! To anyone else making this change: don't forget to (most likely manually) update your references to the table, e.g. changing `Table \ref{yourlabel}` to `Figure \ref{yourlabel}`.

Comment: @SSilk If you use the `cleveref` package then you don't have to worry.